# Compacting list into local groups with respect to provided similarity

Tags: c#, linq, extension-methods

I would like to create `Compact` extension method for `IEnumerable<T>` which will allow me to work almost like `GroupBy` but will create *local* groups - meaning they should be two or more groups with the same key if they are separated with items with another key:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Compact<T, TKey, TResult>(
        this IEnumerable<T> source, 
        Func<T,TKey> keySelector, 
        Func<TKey, IEnumerable<T>, TResult> resultSelector);
```

where `keySelector` is to extract the key for each element and `resultSelector` is a function to create a result value from each group (exactly as in [one of GroupBy overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb549393%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)).

Assuming I have class and data like this:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public string Name;
    public double Value;
    public SomeClass(string name, double value)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Value = value;
    }
}

var input = new List<SomeClass>() { 
    new SomeClass("X", 2.0), 
    new SomeClass("X", 3.0), 
    new SomeClass("Y", 1.0),
    new SomeClass("X", 4.0),
    new SomeClass("Z", 0.0),
    new SomeClass("Z", 1.0)
};
```

example usage would be:

```
var output = input.Compact(x => x.Name, 
                           (key, values) => values.Average(v => v.Value));
```

which should result in list with values `2.5`, `1.0`, `4.0` and `0.5`.

I've created almost working method:

```
public static IEnumerable<TResult> Compact<T, TKey, TResult>(this IEnumerable<T> source, 
    Func<T,TKey> keySelector, 
    Func<TKey, IEnumerable<T>, TResult> resultSelector) 
{
    if (!source.Any())
        yield break;
    var comparer = EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default;
    TKey previousKey = keySelector(source.First());
    List<T> group = new List<T>() { source.First() };
    foreach (var item in source.Skip(1))
    {
        TKey currentKey = keySelector(item);                
        if (!comparer.Equals(previousKey, currentKey))
        {
            yield return resultSelector(previousKey, group);
            group.Clear();
        }
        group.Add(item);
        previousKey = currentKey;
    }
    if (group.Any())
    {
        yield return resultSelector(previousKey, group);
    }
}
```

but I feel it could be written in much more elegant way and what is worse, is not working properly in following case:

```
var output = input.Compact(x => x.Name, (key, values) => values);
```

it creates collection of four identical elements with the list inside containing only last item (with `Z` and `0.0` values). I would rather expect it to be list of lists with two, one, one and two items respectively.

Do you have any thoughts how it can be improved and corrected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `group.Clear();` try:

```
group = new List<T>();
```

You are using the same `group` in your method. You are returning it then clearing it, last time you add `Z` to the group all groups are having `Z` because they are all the same.

Edit: You can improve your method by getting the enumerator of your `source`, instead of using `First` and `Skip` over and over again:

```
var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();
int i = 0;
TKey previousKey = default(TKey);
List<T> group = null;
while (enumerator.MoveNext())
{
     if (i == 0)
     {
          previousKey = keySelector(enumerator.Current);
          group = new List<T>() {enumerator.Current};
          i++;
     }
     else
     {
         TKey currentKey = keySelector(enumerator.Current);
         if (!comparer.Equals(previousKey, currentKey))
         {
              yield return resultSelector(previousKey, group);
              group = new List<T>();
         }
         group.Add(enumerator.Current);
         previousKey = currentKey;
     }

}
```

Comment: Stupid me, of course you are right! nevertheless, do you have any ideas about improving this method? I quite do not like those `First`s and `Skip(1)`...